# How do you display a float number?

Tags: c++

This is my C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1;
    char c;
    int num[100], tokenvalue = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    f1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while ((c = getc(f1)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c))
        {
            tokenvalue = c - '0';
            c = getc(f1);
            while (isdigit(c))
            {
                tokenvalue = tokenvalue * 10 + (c - '0');
                c = getc(f1);
            }
            num[i++] = tokenvalue;
            ungetc(c, f1);
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe no's in the program are\n");
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", num[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    int z;
    scanf("%d", &z);
    return 0;
}
```

My test.txt input file has:

```
Name: Md. Jakir Hossin
Age: 23

Name: Shafi Mahmud
Age: 18.5

Name: Asmaul Husna
Age: 28

Name: Md. Jahirul Haque
Age: 30.4
```

Output:

![output][1]

This program shows any int number, but doesn't show float number. How do you display a float number?

Comment: user `%f` as format specifier

Comment: Why are you using stdio in C++ code (tagged as such). It is C code

Comment: @EdHeal there is still hundreds of people who do not know the difference / thinks c++ is higher version of c :D

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi - If you are going to change the tag why not change the first line of the question?

Comment: Is this C or C++? Or even Turbo C++...?

Comment: Once you've figured out printing `float`s, at some point you're going to have to deal with the challenge that your program won't currently read them in. You'll have to get them in there somehow, if you want a fighting chance at being able to print them one day.

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;`

Comment: @EdHeal `stdio` is a part of C++. I have trouble understanding why so many regular posters are unaware of this.

Comment: I have rolled back the language-changing edit [in accordance with the meta policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker)

Comment: @MattMcNabb - It is there for backwards compatibility. Should not be used in modern code as it does not enforce type safety.

Comment: @EdHeal it's safe if used correctly and unsafe if used incorrectly, like many things in C++ . There are reasons to use cstdio instead of iostream (which are beyond the scope of this comment!) but in either case it's not our role to enforce a particular programming paradigm by editing the question. (By all means post an answer including that suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

To display a float number is well done with:

```
printf("%f", 1.23f);
```

If the number or variable is not a `float`, a cast will work:

```
int num[100];
....
printf("%f", (float) num[j]);
```

Note: that variadic values passed to `...` functions like `printf()` convert such values to `double`.

Yet OP's real issue seem to be that the number needs to be read from the file as some floating point value.

```
// int num[100];
float num[100];
...
// Age: 18.5
char buf[50];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f1) == NULL) Handle_IOError_or_EOF();
if (sscanf(buf, "Age:%f", buf, &num[j]) != 1) Handle_UnexpectedData();
printf("Age: %.1f\n", num[j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

C++:

```
cout << num[j] << endl;
```

or

C:

```
printf("%f \n", num[j]);
```

Comment: either you have to do type conversion or declare as float

Comment: But the declaration is `int num[100]`, so the C version is not going to work, and in fact will invoke undefined behaviour.